# NHibernate with XML as a database?

Tags: xml, nhibernate

We have a project, where we need to use NHibernate to perform CRUD operation with XML or a Flat file (.txt) as a database.

Can we use NHibernate with other than a RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

### short answer

yes

### long answer

it will be quite some work because the minimum would be to implement IConnection, ICommand, Driver and a Parser to translate sql into XPath or whatever.

It would be much easier to load the Xml/Txt into an (in-memory) SQLite database in a format best suited for the use case and query that through NHibernate.

Comment: You mean to say we can achieve in two ways?

Comment: yes: a) write your own abstraction over XML/Txt which simulates a relational database or b) use a lightweight, filebased  relational database like sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). It is not a RDBMS. Although it is a relational database, it's not a  "Management System". There is no server, just a file. There is no installation and no configuration, just a dll and a connect string ...

I don't think that it makes sens to use NH for something else as a relational database.